# Adicionar ou Remover Class de uma DIV ao clicar

Tags: javascript, jquery, classes

Olá galera estou querendo fazer com que quando eu aperto 1x na DIV "pacotes .PA" ela vai fazer as alterações:

- adicionar classe **.select**
- CSS: #bottaaoPA: Display:Block ;
- CSS: bottaaoPB: Display:None;
- CSS: bottaaoPC: Display:None;

E quando eu aperta novamente ele vai remover a classe **.select**

```html
<div class="pacotes pa">
    <h1> PACOTE COMPLETO</h1>
    <h2 style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px;">R$<b>2.500,</b></h2>
    <h6 style="display:inline-block;">00</h6>
    <div class="bloco-loja">
        <h1>Transfer</h1>
        <h2>(participante + bike)</h2>
        <h3>Vitória x Itaúnas<br> Praia das Neves x Vitória</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="bloco-loja">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:5px;">Pousada/Hotel</h1>
        <h3>09 diárias c/ café da manhã</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="bloco-loja">
        <h1>Carro de Apoio <br> e de Bagagem</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bloco-loja">
        <h1>Kit Evento</h1>
        <h2 style="margin-top:10px;">Camisa Ciclista + Medalha de <br> Conclusão da Expedição + <br> Adesivo do Evento</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="bloco-loja">
        <h1>Seguro</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottaaoPA">Comprar</div>
```

Comment: Kaique, evite usar css inline e sempre que possivel crie um exemplo de fácil verificação,  você pode utilizar o     https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: olá @GabrielRodrigues então, essa pergunta não tinha muito oque se amostrar, então não precisa do jsfiddle.. eee pq não usar o inline? eu uso o display: inline:block apenas pois axo ele melhor do que usar o float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ficaria assim (sobra a `class`, você não vê ele alterando no código `HTML`, mas ele adiciona):

```js
$(function(){
  var contador = 0;

  $('.pacotes').click(function(){

    if(contador === 0)
    {
      $(this).addClass("select");
      $("#bottaaoPA").css("display","block");
      $("#bottaaoPB").css("display","none");
      $("#bottaaoPC").css("display","none");
      contador = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).removeClass("select");
      $("#bottaaoPB").css("display","block"); //apenas para teste
      contador = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pacotes pa">
 <h1> PACOTE COMPLETO</h1>
 <h2 style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px;">R$<b>2.500,</b></h2><h6 style="display:inline-block;">00</h6>
 
 <div class="bloco-loja">
    <h1>Transfer</h1> 
    <h2>(participante + bike)</h2> 
    <h3>Vitória x Itaúnas<br> Praia das Neves x Vitória</h3>
 </div>
 
 <div class="bloco-loja">
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:5px;">Pousada/Hotel</h1> 
    <h3>09 diárias c/ café da manhã</h3>
 </div>
 
 <div class="bloco-loja">
    <h1>Carro de Apoio <br> e de Bagagem</h1> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="bloco-loja">
    <h1>Kit Evento</h1> 
    <h2 style="margin-top:10px;">Camisa Ciclista + Medalha de <br> Conclusão da Expedição + <br> Adesivo do Evento</h2> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="bloco-loja">
    <h1>Seguro</h1> 
 </div>
</div>

<div id="bottaaoPA">ComprarPA</div>
<div id="bottaaoPB">ComprarPB</div>
<div id="bottaaoPC">ComprarPC</div>
```

Ao clicar pela primeira vez ele vai ocultar as divs `PB` e `PC` e atribuir uma classe `select` a `div.pacotes`, ao clicar novamente ele ele remove essa class e exibe a div `PB` (apenas para ver funcionando aqui).

Comment: é funciono amigo, mas queria que depois de ter retirado a classe, e eu apertasse de novo ele adicionasse a classe novamente e por ae sucessivamente a cada click

Comment: Ele adiciona a classe novamente amigo, por isso mesmo coloquei para também exibir a `div.bottaaoPB`, para você ver que ele ta tirando e colocando a classe. Qualquer coisa recarregue essa página, pois eu tinha esquecido do `contado = 0;` e por isso não estava colocando a classe novamente.

Comment: sim agora foi obrigado :)

Comment: eu no caso fiz 3 pacotes PA , PB e PC. como faço para que se um pacote tiver selecionado  e eu aperto em outro ele desativa esse pacote e ativa o outro?
tipo no meu caso, o PA ta ativo, ae eu aperto no PB ele ativa o PB e desativa o PA

Comment: Bom, no caso cada pacote seria uma `div`? Basta no click delas ver se há classe nas demais (com `hasClass`) e com isso remover a classe `select` das demais. Tenta tomar a partir desse comentário, se não consegui publique outra pergunta com a dúvida que eu os outros membros responderemos.

Comment: ok irei tentar obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Pode utilizar o método `toggleClass()` do jQuery:

```
$(".pacotes").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("select");
});
```

Comment: não ta criando classe não :/

Answer (score 2):

Tente alterar para :

```
<div id="bottaaoPA" onclick="if(this.hasClassName('select')){ this.className = ''}else{ this.className = 'select' };">ComprarPA</div>
```

Com JS puro.